# Por Qué? cuando uso este while pongo el primer número y despues se repite un bucle infinito y ponga lo que ponga sale la misma respuesta

Tags: javascript, while

aca les dejo el codigo quiero hacer una especie de juego para adivinar un número pero despues de poner el primer número entra en un ciclo infinito, supongo que es debido al while, pero necesito  ayuda para saber bien problema

```
let NumeroAdivinar = prompt(`ESCRIBE NÚMERO QUE CREAS QUE ES`)
let NumeroMisterioso = parseInt(Math.random(0, 1) * 50)
while (NumeroAdivinar !== NumeroMisterioso) {
    if(NumeroAdivinar > NumeroMisterioso) {
        alert(`Número alto
Prueba uno mas bajo por favor`)
        prompt(`Escribe Nuevo Número`)
    }
    else if(NumeroAdivinar < NumeroMisterioso) {
        alert(`Número bajo
      Prueba uno mas alto por favor`)
        prompt(`Escribe Nuevo Número`)
    }

    else if(NumeroAdivinar === NumeroMisterioso){
        alert("felicidades")
    }
    else{
        alert("por favor usa un número de 0 a 50")
    }
    prompt("intenta DE NUEVO");
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisando tu codigo he consiguido una serie de errores por lo cual no te esta ejecutando correctamente:

1. No estas terminando las lineas de comando con el **punto y coma ;**
2. Dentro del `while` no existe ningun mecanismo de carga para la variable NumeroAdivinar, tienes los `prompt()` sin recibir datos
3. El bucle `while` que estas usando no es el conveniente para este ejemplo porque la evaluacion esta en la cabecera de la primera linea y lo que buscas es evaluar al final. recomiendo usar `do {} while()`
4. La comparacion que tienes en el while para diferente no es correcta, debes usar **`!=` en lugar de `!==`**
5. No se necesitas varios `prompt()` para la entrada del numero con uno solo que lea al inicio  del bloque `do {} while()` es mas que suficiente.
6. El ultimo **else** no sera ejecutado porque los 3 primero tomaran el valor del numero de entrada, esto se puede corregir colocandolo al inicio del **if()**.

Te anexo el nuevo codigo para el resolver el problema:

```
   <script>
    
    let NumeroMisterioso = parseInt(Math.random(0, 1) * 50);

    do {
        // entrada de datos
        NumeroAdivinar = prompt('Escribe Nuevo Número');
        
        if (NumeroAdivinar > 50 || NumeroAdivinar < 0) {
            alert("por favor usa un número de 0 a 50");
        } 

        else if(NumeroAdivinar > NumeroMisterioso) {
            alert('Número ALTO Prueba uno mas bajo por favor');     
        }

        else if(NumeroAdivinar < NumeroMisterioso) {
            alert('Número BAJO Prueba uno mas alto por favor');
        }

        else {
            alert("felicidades"); 
            //  introducir el código aquí  
        } 
    
    } while (NumeroAdivinar != NumeroMisterioso);

    </script>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo me sirvio muchisimo

Comment: Es muy necesario el punto y coma ?

Comment: Es una practica  programacion usar al final de cada sintaxis el punto y coma para indicarle al interprete o compilador que se ha terminado la linea, pero hay excepciones a la regla por ejemplo cuando se aplica una sola linea de codigo en un bloque if() o  en  un bucle que tenga {}  pero esto tambien depende del lenguaje, he leido que JavaScript es opcional pero ya estoy acostumbrado a usarlo y lo pongo tambien aqui: te coloco u link para leer mas informacion: http://diegoboscan.com/usar-punto-y-coma-en-javascript/

Answer (score 3):

En principio el `while` es infinito porque la condición no cambia nunca, para que cambie, tienes que asignar los nuevos valores que el usuario va poniendo a `NumeroAdivinar`, de otra manera siempre va a evaluar los valores iniciales.

Un segundo tema es que `NumeroAdivinar === NumeroMisterioso`, que sería el caso exitoso, nunca va a ser evaluado dentro del `while` porque la misma condición del `while` es que sean distíntos, por eso convendría sacarlo del while. Te dejo un ejemplo con esos cambios:

```js
let NumeroMisterioso = parseInt(Math.random(0, 1) * 50);
let NumeroAdivinar = +prompt(`ESCRIBE NÚMERO QUE CREAS QUE ES (${NumeroMisterioso})`);

while (NumeroAdivinar !== NumeroMisterioso) {
  if (NumeroAdivinar > NumeroMisterioso) {
    alert(`Número alto
Prueba uno mas bajo por favor`)
    prompt(`Escribe Nuevo Número`)
  } else if (NumeroAdivinar < NumeroMisterioso) {
    alert(`Número bajo
      Prueba uno mas alto por favor`)
    NumeroAdivinar = +prompt(`Escribe Nuevo Número`)
  } else {
    alert("por favor usa un número de 0 a 50")
  }
  NumeroAdivinar = +prompt("intenta DE NUEVO");
}

if (NumeroAdivinar === NumeroMisterioso) {
  alert("felicidades")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que el promp te guarda un string y el parse del segundo número un entero, y al tener los operadores de comparación con !== y === estás comparando que sean incluso del mismo tipo, es decir un "3" no es igual a un 3 por ejemplo